# how to give a unique id to firebase-query inside a dom repeat so i can clear its path every time data is fetched?

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

i have the following code in polymer

```
   <template id="repeater" is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]" as="mydata">
           <firebase-query
                 id="query"
                 app-name="app name"
                 path="temp/check/[mydata.$key]"
                 data="{{tempdata}}">
           </firebase-query>
           <!--I am Displaying Data here -->
           <!-- Once data is displayed i want to fetch the firebase query id='query' 
                and set its path to null so next time inside dom repeat it gets 
                the required fields and not null objects-->
   </template>
```

Anyone have any idea how to give a unique id to firebase query or how to set the path null once data is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is wrap my `firebase-query` element inside its own component.  That way you don't have to worry about unique id's.

Outer component:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[filteredItems]]" as="evt">
    <firebase-item firebase-path="{{evt.path}}"></firebase-item>
</template>
```

Inner component (`firebase-item`):

```
<firebase-query id="whateverYouWant" path="[[firebasePath]]"></firebase-query>
```